# How to generate Java classes from REST

Tags: webservice-client

With SOAP WebSevices and WSDL it's very easy to generate a Java WebService client with wsimport.

Is there a similar way to do this for Java REST clients?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Alchemy Rest Client Generator](https://github.com/strandls/alchemy-rest-client-generator/). It can generate a jersey 2.0 java client for your JAX-RS REST services by integrating into your server builds.

The client will mimic the exact service API. However this project does not yet support WADL and does not handle marshalling and demarshalling of your transfer objects.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a WADL descriptor for your REST service?

If so, you can use [wadl2java](http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html) or maybe something built-in in your IDE (IDEA for example has a wizard for that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No unfortunately I don't have a WADL. Is there a way to generate it from a example JSON?

Comment: Don't think so, as JSON is just a data interchange format, and doesn't say anything about service used to get it. You can generate classes based on JSON, and use them for representation of data returned from the service - look at this: http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/